# Xtext - how to use "import" in own grammar

Tags: dsl, xtext

I have an own Xtext grammar definition:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyOtherDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myOtherDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyOtherDsl"

OtherModel:
    Foo | Bar;

Foo: 'foo' name=ID;

Bar: 'bar' name=ID;
```

Now, I want to use this grammar in the (standard example) Xtext grammar via an "import":

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

import "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyOtherDsl" as other

Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*
    foobars+=FooBar*;

Greeting: 'Hello' name=ID '!' foo=[other::Foo];

FooBar:  other::Foo | other::Bar;
```

While `Greeting: 'Hello' name=ID '!' foo=[other::Foo];` is working, `FooBar:  other::Foo | other::Bar;` throws an error: *no viable alternative at input 'other'*. In the `Greeting` rule I use the reference for an attribute (`foo`). In the `FooBar` rule I just want to use it as a type. How can I do it?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: Hi what is your intended behaviour? do you want to call the rule from the other grammar? this only works with inheritance

Comment: Hi Christian, I have a very large DSL grammar and want to split it into different parts (i.e. separated .xtext files in one project). For instance, the grammar is splitted into A.xtext, B.xtext and C.xtext and one general G.xtext (for own terminals, etc.). A, B and C are using grammar mixing (keyword 'with') to inherit from grammar G. But I also need to combine A, B and C into one grammar again, that is why I want to use 'import' here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xtext only Supports a Single Inhertiance Hierarchy

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslBase with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslGrandParent with org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslBase
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslParent with org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslGrandParent
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslChild with org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslParent
```

so it is not possible to spilt them up into several and group them togther in one dsl

Comment: Why can't I use the keyword `import` to use additional grammars (besides the one I mix into my grammar with the keyword `with`)? In the example above, I can use `import` without any problems for the `Greeting` rule, but not for the `FooBar` rule. Is there an intended behaviour by Xtext to just use imported rules in (cross-)references and not in rules consisting of alternatives? Edit: from the answer above I assume that it is not possible. So it is basically not a good idea to split a grammar into separate files (when I cannot build a strict hierarchy)?

Comment: imports is for importing metamodels!!! (EClasses etc.) and not about grammars (rules etc.) if you do the cross ref other::Foo you simply use the metamodel and NOT the grammar

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that. I'll accept your answer, because apparently there is no (good) way to split a grammar into separate files. Using the keyword `with` is not helpful when you also have cross-dependencies between the splitted grammars (e.g., grammar `A` extends from general grammar `G`, but also needs some rules from grammar `B`). If there exist another way, please let me know.

Comment: cross dep problems you can always workaround if you use a manually maintained metamodel or moving them up to the base grammar